# Comparing two textbox values in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am usingh VB.net, I have two textboxes please see below:

```
<tr id="trCheckedBy2" runat="server">
    <td>
    Application Checked by 1:
    </td>
    <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="CheckedBy1TextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CheckedBy1") %>' />
    </td>
    <td>
    Application Checked by 2:
    </td>
    <td >
    <asp:TextBox ID="CheckedBy2TextBox"  runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CheckedBy2") %>' />
    </td>                                
</tr>
```

Now I want to give error message **"Username can not be same"** when **CheckedBy2TextBox** text is same as **CheckedBy1TextBox**. It would be good if we can use .net validator.

Please suggest!

Thanks.

Best Regards,
MS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [CompareValidator control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db330ayw(VS.80).aspx) with the `Operator` property set to `NotEqual`:

```
<asp:CompareValidator runat="server"
                      ControlToValidate="ID_Of_First_TextBox"
                      ControlToCompare="ID_Of_Second_TextBox"
                      Operator="NotEqual"
                      ErrorMessage="Error_Message_Goes_Here" />
```

Comment: If you see my tr id is runat="server" it is not recognizing my comparevalidator. Its giving error " System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCellCollection must have items of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell'. 'asp:CompareValidator' is of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompareValidator'."

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using `<tr runat="server">` but if your `<tr>` tag is `runat="server"`, you should set `runat="server"` on the `<td>` too.